# What version of TLS does AWS s3cmd uses and how to upgrade it to TLS1.2

Tags: amazon-s3, tls1.2

What version of TLS does AWS s3cmd uses and how to upgrade it to TLS1.2.

I am using aws s3cmd in my bash script for writing files to S3, but recently received an email from AWS that its receiving request using TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1. So I am wondering how do I check what version of TLS is being used currently and how to upgrade it.

Comment: You can check this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z-RuiAkt5no&ab_channel=AWS-CloudCraft).

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the source code I found that its related to Python 2.7 and its SSL dependencies. You'll need to update your Python and other dependencies. A quick fix is to disable HTTPS (to transfer non sensitive data)